# What kind of glove is being shown in the following pictures, and why is it nearly always a knife user who wear this style of gloves?

Tags: requiem-for-the-phantom

I've been searching for information for the past five or six years on what kind of gloves that Ein is wearing in the following pics from the digitalized novel *Phantom of Inferno*. (She also wears them in the three-episode OVA series, *Phantom: The Animation*).

I've noticed that this particular kind of glove is often used by knife wielders; such as Kuro from the *Fate/Stay Illya* series, Chloe from *Noir*; Yuna's sprite in the free *SAO:IF* app; and the Prince character in the manga *Snow White with the Red Hair*, just to name a few. I have more pictures that I can upload if that would aid anyone in recognizing what kind of glove she is wearing.

I've already tried google searching several images in my research-glove-comparison folder, but the only thing that comes close would be a middle-loop finger glove, which lacks the single, solid loop seen in the first and second images.

To boil this all down: what specific kind of glove is she wearing in the images below, and *why* is this particular type of glove -to the point of synonymous association in my eyes- used by close-combat knife wielders?

1. First pic is to show what the glove would look like from the view of the palm, and while holding a knife. (in the knifeless hand, you can see the loop part of her other glove)

   [image]
2. Second pic is to give a close-up, side view of the glove.

   [image]
3. Bottom picture is to show how the glove fits around the middle finger, as also shown in the top picture.

   [image]

I just desperately want to know what kind of glove she is wearing, so that I have that small, wonderful tidbit of information to add to what I know about my favorite, dopamine-fuel-for-my-brain-every-time-I-think-of-her, character.

Comment: I notice more that these are used by female characters than male, but they never stuck out as a knife thing.  I seem to see them more with ninjas, so that might explain the knives.

Comment: Typical Shinobi attire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These gloves are called "finger loop sleeved gloves" but are sometimes also referred to as "(long) Fingerless sleeved gloves".

They more often than not come with no holes at all, or with only a thumb hole. However, the one in the picture is not unheard of either

The image below comes from an [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Silver-Costume-Gloves-Latex-Arm-Warmers-Sleeve-Diamond-Ends-with-Finger-Loop-M21-/254172866660) search on "sleeved gloves", similar results can be found on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/BLACK-FISHNET-FINGER-SLEEVE-GLOVES/dp/B072XFMKMX) as well.

[image]

Comment: As for the 'why is this used by knife users part' I haven't really found a connection just yet. I might look into that at a later point in time ;)

Comment: I tried looking for the image via a eBay search using the phrase you did, but the picture did not come up; just more of the cursed not^ gloves. Can you provide a direct link to the shop/cart/buy page thing so I can do some investigating at a later time?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Added a link for both ebay and amazon. Also added a search term which gives even more accurate results ;)

Comment: Total speculation, but I'd guess it wouldn't be super difficult to add some hard material to the back of the hand to make some kind of armor.  Something like that could be valuable in close quarters combat.  I'd also suspect that being fingerless means bulky material won't impair someone's ability to use their fingers (also valuable when wielding knives/small weapons).

Comment: @Becuzz Same road I was going with my thoughts [I figured something along these lines](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50222556#50222556)